# How to get the path of one directory up from the current script path in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I wanted to get the path of one directory up in tcl as a string without using something like "cd .."
here is the following code i want to do

```
set script_path [ file dirname [ file normalize [ info script ] ] ]
puts $script_path
>>> example/foo
#add the needed code here 
puts $script_path 
>>> example
```

Comment: You already seem to know that `file dirname` gives you the directory a path is in. Just apply it one more time to go up another level: `set script_path [file dirname $script_path]`

Answer (score 1):

The `file dirname` command just lops one element off the end of the path each time, with a bit of trickiness to handle what happens when it runs out.

```
set path "example/foo/bar.tcl";  # You can get this from [info script] or whatever

puts $path;                      # ==> example/foo/bar.tcl
set path [file dirname $path]
puts $path;                      # ==> example/foo
set path [file dirname $path]
puts $path;                      # ==> example
set path [file dirname $path]
puts $path;                      # ==> .
```

Use it as many times as you need. (You might want to `file normalize` the path before you start doing this, which will convert the path into absolute form.)